# Only use one specific part of cordova plugin

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm using [cordova vr player](https://github.com/jleszczynski/cordova-vr-player) to play VR videos in my app. VR view's docs state that "some older devices cannot decode video larger than 1080p (1920x1080)".

In my app, the user downloads the video file first, so it's not streaming the video.

I have two videos: one for newer devices (in 4k), and one for the older devices (in 1080p).

The plugin I'm using, supports adding a fallback video when the device isn't able to decode a video:

```
 @Override
    public void onLoadError(String errorMessage) {
      // An error here is normally due to being unable to decode the video format.
      loadVideoStatus = LOAD_VIDEO_STATUS_ERROR;
      //Attempt to load fallback video
      if (!fallbackVideoLoaded){
        fallbackVideoLoaded = true;
        launchVideoLoader(fallbackVideoUri);
      }else {
        Toast.makeText(
                VrVideoActivity.this, "Error loading video: " + errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
      }
      Log.e(TAG, "Error loading video: " + errorMessage);
    }
```

I want to know on app start-up if the device will be able to decode 4k, so I can offer the user the correct video to download.

It's probably a long shot, but I was wondering if it would be possible to alter the plugin, so that I just checks the decoding. I don't want the player to open up etc., it should just try the decoding of a very short baked-in 4k video.

Unfortunalty, I don't have much experience with native plugins. Anyone who can point me in the right direction? My guess it I should intersept the decoding part in [this file](https://github.com/jleszczynski/cordova-vr-player/blob/master/src/android/java/neotrino/VrVideoActivity.java).

Comment: you can fork the plugin on github, make any changes and use this for your app